# AngularJS dynamic ng-option to link two drop downs

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, ng-options

Can anyone help me with a ng-option issue, I am trying to have ng-option created dynamically. What I am doing is pretty complex but I tried to explain it in following link 
I have two drop downs the first one has values like county, municipality and district based on whats selected in first drop down box the second drop down box will have either county or municipality or districts populated. but the trick is that the json for county or district or municipality have different structure so the ng-option for the second drop down has to be dynamic. please help

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select id="FeatureTypeDropdown" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="factory.geography.featuretype" ng-options="ft as ft.type for ft in featuretype" ng-change="SimpleMethod(featuretype.selected)">
        <option value="">Select a Feature Type...</option>
    </select>
    <select id="Select1" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="factory.geography.county" ng-options="c as c.CountyName for c in County" multiple>
        <option value="">Select a Feature...</option>
    </select>    
</div>
```

ang

```
ular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){

        $scope.featuretype = [
                    { type: 'County' },
                    { type: 'Municipality'},
                    { type: 'District'}
    ];
    $scope.County = [{ CountyName: 'C1', countyNumber: '01' }, { CountyName: 'C2', countyNumber: '02' }, { CountyName: 'C3', countyNumber: '03' }, { CountyName: 'C4', countyNumber: '04' }];
    $scope.Municipality = [{ MunicipalityName: 'M1', MunicipalityNumber: '01' }, { MunicipalityName: 'M2', MunicipalityNumber: '02' }, { MunicipalityName: 'M3', MunicipalityNumber: '03' }];
    $scope.Districts = [{ DistrictsName: 'D1', DistrictsNumber: '01' }, { DistrictsName: 'D2', DistrictsNumber: '02' }, { DistrictsName: 'D3', DistrictsNumber: '03' }];    
});
```

visit    http://jsfiddle.net/LfEMw/3/

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LfEMw/4/)

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select id="FeatureTypeDropdown" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="option1" ng-options="ft as ft.type for ft in featuretype">
        <option value="">Select a Feature Type...</option>
    </select>
    <select id="Select1" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="factory.geography.county" ng-options="c as c[option1.displayName] for c in option1.data" multiple>
        <option value="">Select a Feature...</option>
    </select>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.County = [{ CountyName: 'C1', countyNumber: '01' }, { CountyName: 'C2', countyNumber: '02' }, { CountyName: 'C3', countyNumber: '03' }, { CountyName: 'C4', countyNumber: '04' }];
    $scope.Municipality = [{ MunicipalityName: 'M1', MunicipalityNumber: '01' }, { MunicipalityName: 'M2', MunicipalityNumber: '02' }, { MunicipalityName: 'M3', MunicipalityNumber: '03' }];
    
    $scope.Districts = [{ DistrictsName: 'D1', DistrictsNumber: '01' }, { DistrictsName: 'D2', DistrictsNumber: '02' }, { DistrictsName: 'D3', DistrictsNumber: '03' }];
    
        $scope.featuretype = [
            { type: 'County', data:$scope.County, displayName:'CountyName' },
             { type: 'Municipality', data:$scope.Municipality, displayName:'MunicipalityName'},
             { type: 'District', data:$scope.Districts, displayName:'DistrictsName'}
    ];
});
```

Comment: thanks Josep that's exactly what I was looking for, now in real world I am actually getting json back with lot more data for every feature type selected but it works great. Just curious if I need to display values from multiple columns in drop down for example if I have to show M1-01 so both fields MunicipalityName and MunicipalityNumber then what should I do. in normal case my ng-option will be "c as c.MunicipalityNumber +'-'+ MunicipalityName  for c in Municiplaity". How will I do that? any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: @SandeepChaudhary Later on today I will have a look at your new question. Thanks!