# Drop list based on another drop list

Tags: php, html, select, html-select

hope you fine and well,

i have a drop down list that contains categories list as follows:

```
<div  class='form-group'>
    <br/>
        <label class='control-label col-md-2 'for='id_date'>Category</label>
            <div class='col-md-2' class='form-group' class='col-md-11'>
            <select class="form-control " id="sel1" ng-model="category" ng-init="" >
                        <?php
                        mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

                        mysql_select_db('my');

                        $sql = "SELECT category FROM categories";

                        $result = mysql_query($sql);
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo "<option value='" . $row['category'] . "'>" . $row['category'] . "</option>";
                        } ?>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

below this select, i have another select which is to choose element from the category as follows :

```
<div  class='form-group'>
   <br/>
        label class='control-label col-md-2 ' for='id_date'>element</label>
            <div class='col-md-2' class='form-group' class='col-md-11'>
            <select class="form-control"  id="sel12"   ng-model="elemnt" ng-init="" >
                        <?php
                        mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

                        mysql_select_db('my');

                        $sql = "SELECT element FROM elements where category =   ";

                        $result = mysql_query($sql);
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo "<option value='" . $row['element'] . "'>" . $row['element'] . "</option>";
                        } ?>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

how i can make the content of the second drop list to be based on the first drop list ?! e.g how i can put the input of the first drop list in the second SQL statement ?!

regards.

Comment: What I understand is you need dependent dropdown. For this you have to make an ajax call on change of the first dropdwon and then fill the second dropdown with the result of ajax call

Comment: as far I/we can see, you are using angularJS? better look for data binding examples instead of regular php/ajax scripts, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518220/angularjs-dynamic-ng-option-to-link-two-drop-downs

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with only php.

You must use javascript/Jquery and ajax.

Make a php script who load data from a request. 
After change your first select use ajax function who call your php script with the right value and update the second select.

```
<select class="form-control " id="sel1" ng-model="category" ng-init="" >
                        <?php
                    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

                    mysql_select_db('my');

                    $sql = "SELECT category FROM categories";

                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['category'] . "'>" . $row['category'] . "</option>";
                    } ?>
                    </select>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#sel1").change(function(){
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "yourscript.php",
  data: {myval : $(this).val()};
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    //Here append your result in your second select
  });

});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['myval']))
{
  //SQL query where id=myval
  echo $result;//result of query
}
```

Comment: Wait i'll post an example

Comment: @Alexis never say 'never', it can be done with pure PHP logic.

Comment: With only php ? no JS/Jquery ? i want see that :D

Comment: @Alexis: With posts and/or gets.

Comment: Yes you're right but performance and user experience be degraded. And you need to store the first choice each time... You can but it's not the best way ?

Answer (score 0):

Using pure PHP with intermediate submit:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitForm']) && $_POST['submitForm'] == 1){
        //form is submitted by button, proceed with DB stuffs
        echo 'Great, you have submitted the form, will check VALUES and do INSERT.';
    }
?>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="aForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="submitForm" id="submitForm">
        <select name="category" onchange="this.form.submit();">
            <option value="">Choose...</option>
            <option value="1" <?=($_POST['category']==1 && !$_POST['submitForm'])?'selected':'';?>>Cat 1</option>
            <option value="2" <?=($_POST['category']==2 && !$_POST['submitForm'])?'selected':'';?>>Cat 2</option>
            <option value="3" <?=($_POST['category']==3 && !$_POST['submitForm'])?'selected':'';?>>Cat 3</option>
        </select>
        <select name="element">                
            <?php 
            if($_POST['category'] && !$_POST['submitForm']){
                // SELECT from DB based on passed category ID
                echo '<option value="">Now choose element...</option>';
                echo '<option value="1">Elem 1</option>';
                echo '<option value="2">Elem 2</option>';
                echo '<option value="3">Elem 3</option>';
            }else{
                echo '<option value="">Choose category first...</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="button" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('submitForm').value = 1; this.form.submit();">
    </form>
</body>
```

However this is not either the best or most efficient approach, the script only demostrates how can be done without JS as is requested.