# Fill second Select tag base on the first Select tag using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-controller

I'm using UI-Bootstrap so I can use them both Angular and bootstrap. I want to access the value from a select tag that the "controllerCountries" controller have and use that value as a parameter to the fill the select "selectedServices". I want to do that because the logic of the program will be that when I choose a country of a list of countries in a select tag, use that value to fill the another select tag.

My HTML is here:

```
<div  style="margin-top: 15px"  class="col-md-6">
     <div id="form-pais"class="form-group">
         <label class=" control-label">Country:</label>
         <div class="selectContainer">
              <select  ng-controller="controllerCountries" class="form-control" id="abvCountry" name="abvCountry" ng-model="countrySelected">
                   <option value="gt">Guatemala</option>
                   <option value="sl">El Salvador</option>
                    <option value="hn">Honduras</option>
               </select>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 15px"  class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label class=" control-label">Services:</label>
   <div ng-controller="controllerServices" class="selectContainer">
       <select  class="form-control" id="selectServices"ng-model="servicios" ng-options="y for (x, y) in serviciosgt" text="">
       </select>
   </div>
```

My JS file looks like that:

```
//Heres the list of services in the objects. I use this to fill the second select.
app.controller('controllerServices', function($scope)
{
     $scope.serviciosgt =
     {
          consMiami : "Consolidación Miami",
          contCompletosGT: "Contenedores Completos",
          cargMartConsolidadGT : "Carga Maritima Consolidada",
          cargAereaRegularGT: "Carga Áerea Regular"
    };

    $scope.serviciosSL =
    {
         contCompletosSl : "Contenedores Completos",
         cargMartConsolidadSl: "Carga Marítima Consolidada",
         cargAereaRegularSl: "Carga Áerea Regular"
    };

    $scope.serviciosHN =
    {
         contCompletosHN : "Contenedores Completos",
         cargMartConsolidadHN: "Carga Marítima Consolidada",
         cargAereaRegularHN: "Carga Áerea Regular"
    };
});

//Heres the controller to fill.
app.controller('controllerCountries', function($scope)
{
     $scope.countrySelected ='';
     $scope.$watch('countrySelected', function () {
          if($scope.countrySelected=="gt")
          {
               console.log("Select GT");

          }
          else if($scope.countrySelected=="sl")
          {
               console.log("Select SL");
          }
          else if($scope.countrySelected=="hn")
          {
               console.log("Select HN");
          }
     });
});
```

Right now I can access the value of the first "controllerCountries" and log that value on the console, but thats it. And, as you can see, I fill the select with the first object, but I wan them to be dinamic. Can anyone help me please. And if you look that my code is wrong, youre welcome to fix it.

Greetings and thanks.

[HTML view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3azbB.png)

Comment: [Dynamic ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518220/angularjs-dynamic-ng-option-to-link-two-drop-downs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need that `$watch`, you can use [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) to fire a callback when the select value (ng-model) is changed. you can write your `if` statements there.

Second, don't use `ng-controller` on a select, you have [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) to dynamically place nested `<option>` elements inside the `<select>`.

Lastly, if you want to fill select number 2 using a value you've selected from select number 1, just reference the correct data when the ngChange callback is fired

```
$scope.onCountryChange = function (country) {
      if(country=="gt")
      {
           console.log("Select GT");
           $scope.serviciosgt = { ... };
      }
      else if(country=="sl")
      {
           console.log("Select SL");
           $scope.serviciosgt = { ... };
      }
      else if(country=="hn")
      {
           console.log("Select HN");
           $scope.serviciosgt = { ... };
      }
 };
```

your select could look something like this

```
<select class="form-control" 
        name="abvCountry" 
        ng-change="onCountryChange(countrySelected)" 
        ng-options="country for country in countries" ng-model="countrySelected">
</select>
```

While

```
$scope.countries = ["gt", "sl", "hn"];
```